# Save multiple checkbox states

Tags: android, checkbox, savestate

I've used this code to get one checkbox saved for when the user returns, but I need to have many checkboxes throughout the application. I'm sure the best way isn't to copy and paste this code, but can't seem to find what it is.

What would I add or change to make this work with say 10 or more checkboxes?

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save(mCheckBox.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCheckBox.setChecked(load());
}

private void save(final boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean load() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void save (final String checkboxId, final boolean isChecked) {
   // shared prefs yadda
   editor.putBoolean(checkboxId, isChecked).commit();
}
```

Or create a schema of your own (SQLite, etc) and persist that way. In any case, every unique checkbox needs to have a unique id in the persistent store.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your CheckBoxes in an array.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxArr.length; i++) {
        save(i, checkBoxArr[i].isChecked());
    }
}

private void save(int index, boolean isChecked) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check" + index, isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

// etc...
```